# My code is retrieving data only from first field of my database. Please see details

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-hosting

I have written some code which retrieves` data from my firebase database.

The problem is that my code is retrieving data only from the very first field of data in my database and not from all the fields.

I want it to retrieve the data from each and every field of my database.

Here's my code:

```
retrieveRef = new Firebase("https://appname.firebaseio.com/hDetails/");

retrieveRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        hDescription = (String) dataSnapshot.child("hDescription").getValue();
        hImage = (String) dataSnapshot.child("hImage").getValue();
        hLat = (String) dataSnapshot.child("hLat").getValue();
        hLng = (String) dataSnapshot.child("hLng").getValue();
        postedAtTime = (String) dataSnapshot.child("postedAtTime").getValue();
        postedBy = (String) dataSnapshot.child("postedBy").getValue();
        postedOnDate = (String) dataSnapshot.child("postedOnDate").getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), firebaseError.getMessage(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Here's an image of my database:

[image]

The data is getting retrieved only from the very last field, i.e. `f4452618-a073-4868-a9c6-050b055b4861` every time.

Here's `build.gradle` (module:app):

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {

        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
            minSdkVersion 16
            targetSdkVersion 23
            versionCode 5
            versionName "0.4"
            multiDexEnabled true;
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'
        compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.3.1'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.0'
        compile 'com.firebase:geofire:1.1.0'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1'
        compile 'io.github.yavski:fab-speed-dial:1.0.4'
        compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Here's`buid.gradle` (project: projectname):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What's going wrong here?

Please let me know.

Sorry, if question seems to be badly formatted. I'm still a beginner here.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Query class from Firebase

```
 DatabaseReference root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().
 getReferenceFromUrl("https://appname.firebaseio.com/hDetails/");

 Query playlistQuery = root.orderByKey();

 playlistQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
            {

                //Make sure you have a empty constructor to de-serialize it

                YourPOJO playlist = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourPOJO.class);
                playlist.getName(); // Depends on the field names
                playlist.getDetails();
                ....
            }
            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: What is `DatabaseReference` and `FirebaseDatabase` here?

Comment: Read https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android#fix_your_class_references_numbered

Comment: but why am I unable to import these in my project? It says: `Cannot resolve method 'DatabaseReference' or 'FirebaseDatabase'`.

Comment: Add the new Dependencies

Comment: Getting this error:-
`Error:(52, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1`

Comment: // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

Comment: Are trying to migrate your Firebase to Latest version? I have posted answer for your current version have a check.

Comment: please have look at edited question. I have added build.gradle files.

Comment: seems fine, remove the previous firebase dependencies

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath all of the previous ones?

Comment: Still getting the same error: `Failed to resolve: :com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.1` :(

Comment: You have to update your "Google Play Services","Google Repository" and "Android Support Repository" to latest versions in Android SDK.

Comment: Updated answer to newer version of Firebase and added dependencies to be added in build.gradle files.

Comment: what's this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are you using the firebase-client-android artifact?` on this line `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);`?

Comment: @selvakumar how to upgrade `GeoFire` to the latest version.

Comment: @VeereshCharantimath your answer caused a lot of trouble for me! I updated all my code as per the latest firebase version, but then found out that `GeoFire` has not updated yet and then again I have to downgrade all of my code!

Answer (score 0):

This will fetch list of hDetails:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference retrieveRef = database.getReference("hDetails");
    final List<YourPOJO> pojoList = new ArrayList<>();
    retrieveRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            pojoList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                pojoList.add(snapshot.getValue(YourPOJO.class));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Dependencies to add on Top level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
```

App level build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: And seems you are using older version of Firebase. Try to use newer version - https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.

Comment: please have look at edited question. I have added build.gradle files.

Comment: what's this error: `Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Android classes not found. Are you using the firebase-client-android artifact?` on this line `Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);`?

Comment: It's a code conflict between versions. First remove all your older version dependencies and codes and start using fresh integration with latest getting started guide.

Comment: how to upgrade `GeoFire` to the latest version.